# TSQLConnection DB param

Tags: database, delphi, path, firebird2.5, datamodule

i create a Data Module with a TSQLConnection component. I set the params by "visual mode".
But i dont know, how specify the path of my firebird file save in my projectFolder/store/db.fdb.
The project path, may change in the client computer.
Any ideas ?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your connection is not Active in design time.

In FormCreate (or DataModuleCreate) you can do

```
Sql_componentname.DatabaseName := ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + 'yourdb.gdb';
Sql_componentname.Active := true;
```

This is if your db is in the same directory as your program.
Otherwise you could set it elsewhere (from ini or userdirectory)

Otherwise:
Via an inifile in your applicationdirectory you could do this

```
iniFile := TIniFile.Create(ChangeFileExt(Application.ExeName,'.ini')) ;
try
  Sql_componentname.Databasename := iniFile.ReadString('Server','DatabaseName','') ;
finally
  iniFile.Free;
end;
```

And in the ini

```
[server]
databasename=projectFolder/store/db.fdb
```